# Need to access the text of a TextView child of a ListView

Tags: java, android

I have a ListView that contains a list of TextViews, and in my onItemClick() method, I need to get at the string value of the TextView that was clicked. How do I do this?

Here is my onItemClick function:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                Intent startNewActivity=new Intent(getBaseContext(),DetailCurrencyActivity.class);
                startActivity(startNewActivity);



            }
```

Update 1:
This is the custom list adapter where the listview gets populated:

```
//custom list adapter
    public class listRecordAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
        private JSONObject[] listOf_Records=null;
        private Context context;
        private TextView ticker,value,value2,changeval;

        public listRecordAdapter(Context context,JSONObject[] listOf_Records){
            Log.i("Concerts", "artistEventAdapter: constructor");
            this.listOf_Records=listOf_Records;
            this.context=context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {         
            return listOf_Records.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {           
            return listOf_Records[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {           
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            Log.i("CurrencyActivity", "artistListAdapter: getView");
            if(convertView==null){
                convertView=LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.forex_listview_item, null);
            }
            try{

                ticker=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ticker);
                ticker.setText(this.listOf_Records[position].getString("ticker"));
                Log.i("CurrentActivity", "listRecordAdapter: getView ticker->"+ticker.getText());

                value=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.value);           
                value.setText(this.listOf_Records[position].getString("value"));
                Log.i("CurrentActivity", "listRecordAdapter: getView value->"+value.getText());

                value2=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.value2);         
                value2.setText(this.listOf_Records[position].getString("value2"));
                Log.i("CurrentActivity", "listRecordAdapter: getView value2->"+value2.getText());

                changeval=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.changeval);           
                changeval.setText(this.listOf_Records[position].getString("changeval"));
                Log.i("CurrentActivity", "listRecordAdapter: getView changeval->"+changeval.getText());
            }catch(Exception ex){
                Log.i("CurrencyActivity", "listRecordAdapter: getView exiting with exception message->"+ex.getMessage());
            }
            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Post your list implementation.  There is quite a variety of ways you could have done it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getView` method gives you a number of ways of a accessing the data.  Presumably you used some sort of array adapter to give you data to the `ListView` in the first place.   The first int, `position`, gives you the index into your original list. See the [getView docs][1] for details. That is probably the easiest way to get the information.

Otherwise, you could try to find the item with the `View` you are provided.

[1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html#onItemClick(android.widget.AdapterView, android.view.View, int, long)

Comment: I'm new to ListViews and another developer had coded the adapter. It turns out JSONObjects were being stored in the ListView, not TextViews. I used the following line to retrieve the JSONObject:  JSONObject hm = (JSONObject)arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView tv = (TextView) arg1;
String myString = tv.getText().toString();
```

arg1 ( as you have it there at least) is a reference to the root View of the row that was clicked.

Comment: Keep in mind that this will only work if your `ListView` item only contains a single `TextView`, if you have a more complex layout for each item, then you will get a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Which is what he said he has.

Comment: I think the code actually does have more than one textview per row in the listview.